# Keeping Rats Out Of Attic

Tags: attic, gutters

A pest control professional told me that rats could be entering the attic through tiny gaps behind the gutter and up and under the drip guard. To even see the gaps he's talking about, the shingles have to be lifted up (if that makes sense; it's really hard to get a clear photo). His suggested solution is to hire a roofer to install a another strip of flat flashing around the entire house behind the drip guard that pushes up against the bottom of the shingles. This of course would be a very expensive job.

1. Does this fix make sense? I can't find anything about it.
2. Would the quick and dirty option to stuff copper mesh into the the gaps possibly work?

If anyone has ever run into this situation, your feedback and experience would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

RS

Comment: Sounds like a way rats could get in but there should be a less expensive solution. I installed gutter guards, the type that keeps leaves out of your gutters. I've heard rats can crawl up downspouts so you'd also need to keep them from going up the downspout to get in the gutter.

Comment: Platinum Goose is correct. You need to bock any possible entry point with heavy metal mesh (rats will chew though plastic) Also consistent trapping or poison stations in the yard will help keep the population down.

Comment: I use snap traps inside special boxes to exclude non-target species. Poison will kill predators and scavengers--hawks, owls, cats, etc.